# How does group by 'x' work?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I recently came across the following piece of Code

```
from item in collection
group item by 'x' into itemGroup
select new
{
    Amount = itemGroup.Sum(z => z.Amount),
    PrevAmount = itemGroup.Sum(x => x.PrevAmount)
}
```

Normally we group by an attribute of a collection like "group by item.Type". But in the above case what will be the result? Will it be one single record, or will each record will be in one group?

Comment: Have you tried running the code?

Comment: I suspect it will make sure that column x's value is only represented once in the result.

Comment: That is nonsense code. Actually you're creating a group of all items. So you get an `IEnumerable<anonymous type>` with a single item that has two properties. You can get the same with: `var amount=collection.Sum(x=>x.Amount)`.

Comment: @KayNelson there is no column called x or 'x'

Comment: @TimSchmelter so you mean that I will get only one object, irrespective of the number and type of records in collection?

Comment: @Bodhi: yes, because `'x'` is a static/unrelated character that is the same for all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more easy to see what's happening if you'll take a look on your query written in method syntax  (actually all query syntax queries are compiled into method syntax queries). So, your query is same as

```
collection.GroupBy(item => 'x')
```

and some projection (Select operator), which does not matter here. So, what is `item => 'x'`? Its a group key selector. I.e. you pass each item to this anonymous method and it calculates key. This key is used to determine to which group current item should go. Usually you should calculate key based on values of item. Like `item => item.Type` but in this case you just return constant value. So, for all items calculated key value will be same. And you will have single grouping with key `'x'` and all item in this group.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your collection contains following objects:

```
{x=1; z=10}
{x=1; z=20}
{x=2; z=30}
{x=3; z=40}
{x=3; z=50}
```

after executing `group` by you will get an enumeration of 3 items.

Each item (having type `IGrouping<T>`) is an enumerable itself like this:

```
[{x=1; z=10}, {x=1; z=20}]
[{x=2; z=30}]
[{x=3; z=40}, {x=3; z=50}]
```

After that for each element of this enumeration you are creating a new object (the line with `select new`) containing a sum of 'x'-es and 'z'-s of each sub item in a group.

```
[{x=1; z=10}, {x=1; z=20}]           -> {Amount=10+20; PrevAmount=1+1}
[{x=2; z=30}]                        -> {Amount=30; PrevAmount=2}
[{x=3; z=40}, {x=3; z=50}]           -> {Amount=40+50; PrevAmount=3+3}
```

So your result is:

```
{Amount=30; PrevAmount=2}
{Amount=30; PrevAmount=2}
{Amount=90; PrevAmount=6}
```

That's my understanding how your code will work.

Comment: Actually this collection doesn't have a column called x or 'x'!

Comment: Show us the element of collection

Comment: It has these 3 fields- Type, Amount and PrevAmount

Comment: This is very probably the result of your overal query. I am asking about the elements which are initially inside `collection` variable. Try to do `collection.ToArray()` before you start your query and look into it.

Comment: The data is pretty straight-forward. Type can be any one of 'Sold', 'Bought' or 'Leased'. Amount and PrevAmount are normal decimal fields

Comment: why u want group it by 'x', what it even suppose to mean?

Comment: To be used in group by 'x' must be a field. It is not a part of the language or LINQ syntax.

Comment: @Buzka91 That's exactly what I want to know.